# R string extract pattern

Tags: r, string

I have a question regarding to extract letters from a string
For example I have in R one vector like:

```
America, Asia, Europe
```

I want to get all of the upper letters in this format like

`AAE` or `A, A, E`

How can I do this with regmatches and regexpr?

Comment: if you are sure that there is no capital letters within the word, just do `gsub("[a-z]+","",x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `gsub` here:

```
x <- "America, Asia, Europe"
output <- gsub("\\b([A-Z])[a-z]+(?:,\\s*)?", "\\1", x)
output

[1] "AAE"
```

If you want a CSV string output of capital letters, then consider:

```
x <- "America, Asia, Europe"
output <- gsub("\\b([A-Z])[a-z]+(?:,\\s*)?", "\\1, ", x)
output <- sub(", $", "", output)
output

[1] "A, A, E"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! is it also possible to check if for example the letter A is then inside the new expression e.g AAE ?

Comment: I don't understand your follow up question?

Comment: For example if I want to check if the letter A appears in AAE or if the letter E appears in AAE

Comment: Use: `grepl("A", "AAE", fixed=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

A simple `gsub`

```
x <- "America, Asia, Europe"
gsub("[^A-Z]","",x)
[1] "AAE"
```

Comment: Your suggestion is overly simplified.  What happens if a given word happens to have _two_ capital letters, e.g. "South America"?  Your suggestion would leave behind `SA`, which might not be what the OP wants here.  Always consider giving a flexible solution.

Comment: is it also possible to check if for example the letter A is then inside the new expression e.g AAE ?

Comment: @Abcxyz yes, you can use `grepl("A", x)` to check.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, OP asked to extract all capital letters. What if OP wants all the capital letters? in that case "South America" would return `SA` and that would be exactly what OP asked for.